# Mikrotik неудачный downgrade RouterOS

Tags: mikrotik

У меня RB951G-2HnD. И такая беда... Я обновил прошивку через веб-интерфейс.
System->Packages->CheckForUpdates
А потом, когда все получилось, какой-то черт дернул нажать кнопку "Downgrade". Я-то надеялся, что он без проблем откатится назад, и как-то даже не подумал что надо париться, предыдущие прошивки заливать и т. д. В итоге не могу подключиться к роутеру ни через Winbox, ни через Netinstall... Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Как его оживить?!

Comment: Найти в документации как его сбросить до заводских настроек. Наверняка надо что-нибудь нажать и подержать

Comment: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Reset

Comment: Там сброс до зоводских настроек если зажать ресет и включить. Но мой несчастный Микротик после этого не оживает. Есть еще инструкция со специальной программой Netinstall, типа скачиваешь прошивку, подключаешь к компу через патчкорд, прописываешь айпишники и вот это все - тоже не прокатывает.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась по обычной инструкции через программу netinstall. Нюанс заключался в том, что я, видимо, не вырубил все брандмауэры в Win 11 или типа того... Точно не знаю, в чем там дело, мне помог wine в любимой Ubuntu 20.04. То есть, если у вас случится такая беда, попробуйте на другом компе или вообще, как в моем случае, из Linux.